# Unable to connect to Kafka 1.0 Broker On WSL

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a local docker instance of 3 zookeepers and 3 kafka brokers that were running `1.0.0` to make sure updating our environments will work as expected. I created a stream processor on kafka `1.0.0`, and it doesn't consume or produce to any topics - it simply initializes itself.

When I try to run this processor, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.BrokerNotFoundException: 
    Could not find any available broker. 
    Check your StreamsConfig setting 'bootstrap.servers'. 
    This error might also occur, if you try to connect to 
    pre-0.10 brokers. Kafka Streams requires broker version 0.10.1.x or higher.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsKafkaClient.ensureOneNodeIsReady(StreamsKafkaClient.java:251)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsKafkaClient.getAnyReadyBrokerId(StreamsKafkaClient.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsKafkaClient.checkBrokerCompatibility(StreamsKafkaClient.java:348)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.checkBrokerVersionCompatibility(KafkaStreams.java:712)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.start(KafkaStreams.java:746)
        at com.overdrive.dataIntegration.ProcessorRunner$StandardProcessorRunner.StartApplication(ProcessorRunner.scala:29)
        at com.overdrive.streams.StreamProcessor$.main(StreamProcessor.scala:22)
        at com.overdrive.streams.StreamProcessor.main(StreamProcessor.scala)
```

My docker instances are `localzoo1:2181` through `localzoo3:2183`, as well as `localkafka1:9092` through `localkafka3:9094`. With debug mode on, I can see the stream processor's config is being loaded correctly:

```
[2018-01-19 16:09:09,824] INFO [main] StreamsConfig values:
        application.id = test-stream-processor
        application.server =
        bootstrap.servers = [localkafka1:9092]
        //more values available upon request
```

I don't think this is a docker issue for two reasons: (1) this exact setup worked just fine when docker was running a kafka cluster on version `0.11`, with a stream processor also on `0.11`, and (2) I also created a local kafka broker, not in docker, and got the same error.

If I make a console consumer, it doesn't output anything if I use the correct host name (in my case, `localkafka1:9092`), and if I use an incorrect host name (like `abcdefg:9092`), it will error very quickly. All of my topics are empty so it's hard to know how far it's getting. I can't put any data in the topics because nothing seems to be able to fully resolve a connection to the cluster.

Finally, I've been digging around the kafka code and adding print statements, then replacing the jars in my processor and running it. From this, it looks like the node status in `NetworkClient` (in `org.apache.kafka.clients`) is getting stuck in `CHECKING_API_VERSIONS` status. Interestingly, it looks like the variable `discoverBrokerVersions` is final when it needs to not be, so that it can be set to false during the polling process. Making this change allows the processor to connect to the brokers.

In summary - I find it very hard to believe that I found a bug that prevents all stream processors from connecting to brokers in version 1.0, but fiddling with the code has allowed things to start working (or, at least, fully establish a connection). Is this a known issue? Is there something weird in the settings that changed between `0.11` and `1.0.0`?

**Update**: This error only occurs when running the stream processor via WSL; running it via powershell works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Exception can also say that there is no network connection between stream-application and kafka brokers. As we had the same problem, we try first a ping from host where stream-application is to host where kafka brokers are.

Comment: I can ping any individual container just fine, and if I execute bash inside a container, I can still ping any container.